# Unable to change navigation bar tint color under Swift 5

Tags: swift

I had a number of screens, and they were all under the control of a Navigation Controller, which was added in by `Editor -> Embed In - > Navigation Controller`.

This Navigation Controller has its Bar Tint color set to say Orange. So every screen has an orange top bar. So far so good.

But one of the screens is special. This one needs to  change its Bar Tint color dynamically, according to certain internal state of the app.

So far I have tried the following method, but to no avail. The bar tint color remains orange. Note that it was from an *accepted* answers offered to previous similar questions asked here. Also notice that the answer was over 2 years old. So I began to wonder maybe there are new syntax for Swift 5 now?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What changed is not Swift but iOS. Also why are you saying `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor` if you mean bar tint color? They are totally different things.

Comment: What I needed was to change the bar tint color, not the tint. So method 2 is not a correct call to be used here - but the text color didn't change to 'red' when method 2 is in place.

Comment: I used the wrong code but the wrong thing didn’t happen? What kind of question is that? In any case, `appearance` stuff only works in the app delegate. Anyway, as I said, it all depends what version of iOS this is. If this is iOS 13, nav bar appearance works a whole different way.

Comment: method 1 addresses the barTintColor, but it didn't work, so that is the confusing part. I have removed method 2 in order to avoid further confusion. It is iOS13. Can you elaborate a bit more on how to change the bar tint color of a screen programatically for iOS 13, if you happen to know?

Comment: its working great on my end .. i can send you video ..

Comment: have you set any appearance to navigation ?

Comment: In iOS 13, you use the navigation item’s `standardAppearance`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/3198042-standardappearance Set its background color. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarappearance/3197993-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .red
    self.navigationItem.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 13, you use the `backgroundColor` of the `standardAppearance` to do this.

- To set the orange color in general, set the `standardAppearance` of the navigation bar.
- To set the red color just for one view controller, set the `standardAppearance` of that view controller's navigation item.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried: ```let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()    
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .red    
        navigationController?.navigationItem.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance``` within that special view controller's ```viewDidLoad()```, only to see all the top bars remained in orange. Did I miss something here?

Comment: I said nothing about the navigation controller's navigation item. What sense would that make? The navigation controller is not inside a navigation controller. I said the _view controller's_ navigation item.

Comment: Got it. Thank you matt. I will upvote your answer and post the code to achieve this for other people's benefit. Cheers.